# Detect my web application is running on an iPad device

Tags: ipad, web-applications

I would like to know how can I detect that my web application is running trough an iPad device, so I can do some code for iPad devices on my web application.

I'm developing a web application in .NET with C#, SQL Server and [Visual FoxPro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_FoxPro) as databases.

Answer (score 0):

The [iPhone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone) and the [iPad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPad) both have distinct user agents.

An example would be

```
 (iPad; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B314 Safari/531.21.10
```

You can find more information and some sample code in *[How to Identify an Apple iPhone, iPod or iPad Visitor to Your Website](http://www.sitepoint.com/identify-apple-iphone-ipod-ipad-visitors/)*.

Comment: hey thanks, i'm trying to use regular expressions (isMatch method) (aspx c#) to search the word so i can detect the device,  very helpful, thanks very much again

Comment: @Christian Glad I could help. If you think I answered the question please upmod the answer and accept